# replace the local file with download the file in the ftp

Tags: php, ftp

```
<?php
$local_file = "/home/zzh/Desktop/1.txt";
$server_file = "/var/www/helpdesk/1.txt";
$ftpserver = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx";
$port = xx;
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftpserver,$port) or die('can\'t connect to ftp'); 
$ftpname="xxx";
$ftppass = "xxx";
ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpname, $ftppass); 

if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII)) {
echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

i want use this php to login the ftp server download 1.txt to replace the 1.txt in the desktop, but it seems doesn't work, i am using ubuntu. needs help please.

ps. i can connect to the ftp successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It should replace it if IIRC.

If not, why not do

```
if ( file_exists($local_file) ) unlink($local_file)
```

This would go before your ftp_get procedure.